# Unable to configure https on amazon ec2 (centos) tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am configuring ssl self signed certificate on tomcat server using centos on amazon ec2 platform and facing some issues. I step by step follow the following tutorial.

http://tecadmin.net/configure-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat/#

but when open my url https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/ it says "The site cannot be reached" where as the https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ without 8443 port works fine. Can anybody please tell me what is basically the issue with the tomcat 8443 port. In my server.xml I am using the following configuration.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                connectionTimeout="20000"
                redirectPort="8443"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                keystoreFile="/etc/pki/keystore"
                keystorePass="_password_" />
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally its perfect to access without port (443) for HTTPS.
But still if you want access the URL with port number, you can make your URL re-direct from 443 to 8443, you can make use of IPTABLES and make it work it.

sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

sudo /sbin/iptables save

Comment: But what I want to see is the tomcat page that comes when I use the url  [link]http://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/. With the url  [link]https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/ the tomcat page is not appearing instead it is showing me the error that I have mentioned in my question.The url  [link]https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ tomcat page cannot be accessed. Can you guide me how can I then access my deployed application on tomcat, I mean which url should I use to open my application with https??. Thanks!!

Comment: When i access your URL https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com , i am getting certificate not trusted, and if you click on advanced option and do the add exception, you can see the tomcat page.
But if you don't want to see this, please generate the certificate from proper CA like.

Coming to accessing you application deployed in tomcat. If you application name is TestApp which is deployed in your tomcat webapp folder, you can acces like below
https://ec2-52-57-105-24.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/TestApp.